# Spring & Hibernate java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: hibernate, spring, one-to-many

here are my models. There's keyInfo in many-to-one relation with userInfo.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KEY_INFOS")
public class KeyInfo implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "KEY_ID")
private long id;

...
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_INFOS")
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length=10)
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_INFOS_KEY_INFOS", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_ID") })
private Set<KeyInfo> keyInfos = new HashSet<KeyInfo>(0);
....
```

}

My Data Access classes. It uses HibernateDaoSupport and implements custom interface. Also transactions are supported:

```
public class UserInfoDAOImplementation extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserInfoDAO {

@Transactional
public void insertUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
    getHibernateTemplate().save(userInfo);  
}

@Transactional
public List<UserInfo> getAllUsers() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from " + UserInfo.class.getSimpleName());
}
}
```

But after something like that, especially last line:

```
KeyInfoDAO keyInfoDAO = (KeyInfoDAO) context.getBean("keyInfoDAO");
            UserInfoDAO userInfoDAO = (UserInfoDAO) context.getBean("userInfoDAO");

            HashSet<KeyInfo> keyTimeInfos = ((KeyEventCollector) keyEventCollector).getKeyTimeInfos();
            if(nameText.getText() != null && nameText.getText().length() > 0) {
                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(nameText.getText());

                userInfo.setKeyInfos(keyTimeInfos);
                userInfoDAO.insertUserInfo(userInfo);

                List<UserInfo> userInfos = userInfoDAO.getAllUsers();
                for(UserInfo userInfoTmp : userInfos) {
                    double quality = 0;

                    Set<KeyInfo> keyInfos = userInfoTmp.getKeyInfos();
                    System.out.println(keyInfos.size());
                }
            }
```

I have an errors, mentioned rather to query string

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:80)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:34)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:61)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2166)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:627)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1863)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:479)
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:279)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
at com.recognizer.data.access.UserInfoDAOImplementation.getAllUsers(UserInfoDAOImplementation.java:21)
at com.recognizer.gui.CollectorFrame$1.actionPerformed(CollectorFrame.java:71)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really strange, but error was caused by existing only one single space sign in table row column. Solution was not to put single space signs, despite of other white spaces are correct regarded.

PS: the issue concerning the same is at [HHH-7504](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7504) which (as expected) is a Wont-Fix

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the above answer, if a field in a row contains only a single space (' '), this causes Spring Framework to break. This is in spite of other white space characters working fine.

The solution is to never use ' ' as a value in a field in a row.

This happens even when not using hibernate. It is a problem with the Spring Framework and JPA.